# Designing multiple client to single server UDP loggin system

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I'm looking to build a network where around 500 devices send in data to a central server which will sort and process the data that is submitted.  The clients will be written in .Net whilst the server will be written in PHP.

From what I've read UDP appears to be ideal for this as it allows the data to just be sent from the clients to the server with no handshaking etc, the packets are just processed as they are received in whatever order they are received.  There is no specific requirement to send any data back to the client from the server.

Looking at examples on the web it appears that the UDP datagrams either need to be fixed length.  Is this case ?  Or can they be terminated at either end with a specific character so that my script can determine the start and end of each message?

Each client will be sending in a message consisting of information about a different number of objects - sometimes information about one object, other times five or ten.  Having to fix the length of the datagram would mean having to send a message about each object.  I'd rather just send information on all objects in one message.

Given the number of clients I would expect that the server portion would need to be multi-threaded.  In that case I presumably need my script to listen on a specific port and to then open a connection on another port ?

This is to replace an existing system that's using TCP very inefficiently so I want to make sure that I plan it correctly from the outset so any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: Without TCP, there is no way to verify if a message is correctly received (data loss, etc..) so building a system over UDP that ultimately would do the same as TCP seems to me like you have some time to spare. So is there any particular reason why you don't want TCP + Encryption?

Comment: UDP is ideal for things like streaming where it doesn't matter if some bytes here and there get's lost. If you're building an API where you actually care about the data, then use TCP. With UDP you will probably end up with a bunch of broken data.

Comment: I'm not massively concerned if some of the data goes missing as much of it is duplicated anyway.  I already have a system running using TCP which is now struggling to cope with the amount of data that is getting thrown at it.  I've weeded out as much as I can at the client end already ...

Comment: Then perhaps its time for a server upgrade?